# Textbox focus, need to trigger the keydown event for that textbox

Tags: textbox, focus, keydown

I want to trigger the keydown event when the textbox is focus. So that i when i focus out of that textbox google map autocomplete " place_changed" will work fine.

Comment: if you want to trigger keydown it's JavaScript not PHP, you can't do that through PHP

Comment: Yes, i want to do in javascript only.

Comment: @ban17 , Yes I want to do in the javascript only

Answer (score 0):

```js
var el=document.getElementById('inputID');
el.addEventListener("keydown", function(){
console.log('press');
});
Node.prototype.fire=function(type,options){
     var event=new CustomEvent(type);
     for(var p in options){
         event[p]=options[p];
     }
     this.dispatchEvent(event);
}
el.addEventListener("focus", function(){
  el.fire("keydown",{ctrlKey:true,keyCode:90,bubbles:true})
});
```

```html
<input id='inputID'>
```

Comment: Thanks trigger is working fine. What i want in gmap autocomplete address need to select the first .pacitem and then trigger the "place_changed" .